# Offset when drawing selection above canvas

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas

I am trying to draw a selection rectangle above the canvas, to give an indication of where the user is selecting. To accomplish this I have a main container that has a canvas and an absolutely positioned div that is adjusted according to mouse events. On the `mouseup` event I get the x, y, width, height, and call the `fillRect()` on the canvas with those exact coordinates. The problem is that the rectangle on the canvas is shifted a few pixels down and over. Could this be the problem with my css?

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alanzam2223/jg7js6nL/)

```
<div id="canvasContainer">

   <canvas width="300" height="300" id="surface"></canvas>

   <div id="selectionRect">
        <span id="select"></span>
   </div>

  <div class="selectionOutline">
        <span></span>
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offset is the margin of the body.  On the CSS page add:

```
body {
  margin:0px;
}
```

Or you can offset the body margin distance from the canvas location.